# Collaborative editor comments on wagtail?

Tags: content-management-system, editor, wagtail, collaborative

I'm thinking of implementing a comment section in the backend side of a wagtail app. The editors would like to have a place to comment on the page they're editing to leave notes for other editors. I was thinking of adding a "Comments" field in the page and simply not render the comments field in the html template. Do you think this would be a decent solution or is there a third party library that can do this or is it built into wagtail and I didn't know about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very timely question! See

https://github.com/wagtail/rfcs/pull/50

published two hours ago :) We'd welcome your input on the RFC.

Comment: Nice! Very timely indeed, thank you for linking :) Hope the PR gets in there soon, I will try out wagtail-review in the meantime.